# Refrigerator fresh food section not cold enough

Tags: refrigerator

I have an Amana top freezer refrigerator and I recently measured the temperatures.

Manufacturer says 0F for freezer and 40F for fresh food.

So my freezer was -10F and fresh food about 55F

I adjusted the freezer thermostat and now the temperature is correct in the freezer compartment.

But no matter what I try, the lowest temp I get in the fresh food compartment is about 50F but nothing lower, even when I set the fresh food compartment's temp to the lowest.

The air flow appears to be fine (from freezer to fresh food) and there are no obstructions.

So my refrigerator has no problem cooling (it managed to maintain -10F in freezer compartment).

Ideas on what to check?

Comment: There's usually  a fan in the freezer that sends cool air down to the lower area... is it working?

Comment: @jack there's a small opening in the cieling area of the fresh food compartment and there's Cool air coming out of it when the condenser turns on

Comment: side by side or freezer on top?

Comment: freezer on top @ack

Comment: Agree about checking on the fan.  It's usually behind the back panel in the freezer compartment.  If the fan isn't running (I'vw replaced two of them), you'll get some cooling in the refrigerator portion just by the fact that the cold air from the freezer will sink to the bottom.

Comment: @SteveSh the fan is working - when the condenser is on, air comes out from the fan grills in the freezer compartment

Comment: What is your model #?

Comment: Amana TR522SW @ack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I bought some frozen groceries and stored them, I immediately noticed the fresh food compartment temperature started to decrease.

Now it's pretty obvious - more low temp mass in freezer compartment = more friction between air (which circulates) and low temp masses = colder fresh food compartment!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an air flow issue. Did you stock up on food for the pandemic?

Recheck the air flow vent between the freezer and refrigerator to be sure it is fully functional. Especially for ice build up

Make sure that there isn't items in the freezer that are in the way of the vent

Make sure that there isn't items in the refrigerator that are in the way of the vent

Make sure that air can flow around in your refrigerator (too much food and items stuffed in there). Remember that warm air will rise and cold air will sink. There must be room for this natural air flow to occur

Comment: yes I checked that. I am beginning to think the thermometer I am using is not accurate, I've put another one next to it and will check tomorrow morning

Comment: That very well might be the case and it also could be more accurate at one temperature then another. I test my thermometers when I first get them using the ice slurry (0c and 32F) and boiling water (100c/212F) and even the best ones are off. I have had to return several that were off 20 degrees or more at either end.

Comment: No luck, both thermometers display the same temp :/